# Running R and RStudio on Dropbox

Tags: r, dropbox, rstudio

For a collaborative project can you install RStudio (and R itself) on a shared dropbox folder, as well as run the script from that same location?

If yes, is there a special procedure that should be employed in setting that up? I currently have both R and RStudio installed on my PC. Does the collaborator need to have R installed on their computer as well for this to work?

Comment: You can [create a portable version of RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534467-Creating-a-Portable-Version-of-RStudio-for-a-USB-Drive) & [R Portable](http://portableapps.com/node/32898) but I'd go with having the collaborator use their own installed versions and then use `git` or some other source+data code control system vs Dropbox.

Comment: Why not just each install R locally, then open/run the R script saved in DropBox locally?

Comment: Adding to @hrbrmstr's comment, it's useful to note that RStudio integrates well with Git.

Comment: Thanks Alex - and no worries if this needs to be flagged/deleted as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there are two separate aspects to your question:

1. Can you share the R & RStudio application/executables
2. Can you share the R scripts/project documents

Regarding 1, to share the application/executables, you could follow the [portable Rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534467-Creating-a-Portable-Version-of-RStudio-for-a-USB-Drive) approach from @hrbrmstr. That's going to require you providing the correct versions for your collaborator's OS. If you are just working with one person, you may find it easier to have them simply download and install RStudio on their own computer.

If your project requires installing custom libraries from CRAN, make sure to communicate this to your collaborator, as libraries you've installed won't be installed for them.

Regarding 2, sharing the R scripts and project documents is straight forward. They should be able to open these documents and execute them on their own machine.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly easier to install RStudio Server on AWS. I did it and the only thing that was a bit of a pain was managing the users (you need to shell in). Once the users are set up you can set up a shared environment and also each user has their own environment.